# Buttons in UITableview cell doesn't get highlighted on fast clicks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have added custom UIButtons in my UITableview cell. 
Using following code:-

```
UIButton *btnOtherCount=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    btnOtherCount.frame=CGRectMake(577, 43, 110, 60);
    [btnOtherCount setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnOtherCount setTitle:@" Nonfiction - Other - 0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnOtherCount.titleLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    btnOtherCount.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    btnOtherCount.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0f];
    [btnOtherCount setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnOtherCount addTarget:self action:@selector(done:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnOtherCount];
```

The problem is that when I try to click button in cell, it doesn't get highlighted to quick touches or if I clicked fast or continuous touches one after another etc. But When I click steadily and more forcefully (not long press), it gets highlighted.

And important thing is the respective action method is get called in both the cases i.e in slow click and in fast click.

Answer (score 0):

That is a new problem with iOS7.  There is now a scrollview in the view hierarchy of the UITableviewCell.  That scrollview checks if it needs to take over the touch action before the button gets the touchdown event.  There is a hack fix for this, inside your cell initialization add this code:

```
for (id obj in self.subviews)
{
    if ([NSStringFromClass([obj class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"])
    {
        UIScrollView *scroll = (UIScrollView *) obj;
        scroll.delaysContentTouches = NO;
        break;
    }
}
```

this isn't ideal, but it works for my cells.  I don't use the scrollview inside the UITableViewCell, so I can do this hack.  If you need the functions of the scrollview then this might break things for you.

Comment: That is a very fragile fix. It relies on manipulating private classes inside the UIKit. Bad mojo.

Comment: There is also a horrible memory leak with animating tablecells that is fixed by swizzling functions.  Until the internal code is fixed these fragile fixes are all that can be done.  Or you can deal with the new "improved" behavior of iOS7.

Comment: @Putz1103 ,  hey thanx for ur help, but still its not making any difference.

Comment: On the simulator it looked like there was no difference, but on the device it works.  If on the device it is still not working then there's not much else you can do.  This is now the built in iOS7 behavior that cannot be dealt with apart from these hack implementations.